# SharePoint 2013 Application not opening in iPhone

Tags: 2013

I have created an application in office 365 when I used the same application on SharePoint 2013 on premises the application is working fine in Laptop browser and Ipad, but if I am trying to open the same application in iPhone I am unable to see that.the application doesn't even load in iPhone.

I have already used media query and iframe. Please help me

I have checked master page also it all working fine in office 365 but the problem is on SharePoint 2013 on premise

in the browser, it is accessible to all browser the problem in only on iPhone

[image]

Comment: It seems a design issue on a mobile browser. Did you ever test the application from the laptop using Chrome device toolbar?

Comment: i have checked in the simulator of chrome browser